# install older version of mysql using rpm

Tags: mysql, rpm, amazon-linux

I am trying to install mysql 5.1.39  in my docker and my docker is using AmazonLinux as the base OS image.I downloaded the rpm and installed the rpm successfully after resolving dependencies.

```
bash-4.2# rpm -ivh MySQL-server-5.1.39-0.glibc23.x86_64.rpm 
    Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
        package MySQL-server-5.1.39-0.glibc23.x86_64 is already installed

bash-4.2# rpm -qa MySQL*
MySQL-server-5.1.39-0.glibc23.x86_64
```

however when i try to install mysql using the command yum install mysql-community-server it says package not available. After installing the rpm what command do i need to issue to install mysql 5.1.39?

```
bash-4.2# yum install mysql-community-server
Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
amzn2-core                                               | 2.4 kB     00:00     
No package mysql-community-server available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL-server-5.1.39-0.glibc23.x86_64.rpm looked like the generic linux RPM from https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/.

If you `rpm -ql MySQL-server-5.1.39-0.glibc23.x86_64` you will see what files are installed. Another RPM isn't necessary.

This RPM notably depends on glibc23 which is probably the same as RHEL5. You may have troubles on a modern OS. There is a [Centos 5 docker image](http://soaphub.org/imagehub/?q=centos&n=library&o=1) you may want to try to install into. The above site also has a RHEL/Oracle Linux that will probably work with the Centos 5 docker image.

Comment: you'll need to do something special with PID1 - init scripts won't as they background a process and terminate. Look at the Dockerfile of mysql and mariadb